# Can't show result as select option Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My Model name mymodel.php**

```
.....    
function all($table,$order)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from($table);
            $this->db->order_by($order);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                return $query->result();
            }
        } .....
```

**My controller name donate.php**

```
.....
    function index()
    {
      $data = array(
                        'rekening' => $this->mymodel->all('rekening', 'id_rekening ASC'),
                        );
                    $this->load->view('client/donate/index', $data);
                } .....
```

**And this My View in path view/client/donate/index**

```
<?php foreach ($rekening as $rek): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rek->id_rekening; ?>" <?php echo set_select('ke_rekening', $rek->id_rekening); ?>><?php echo $rek->bank .' - '. $rek->atas_nama_rekening; ?></option>
              <?php endforeach ?>
```

But why cant show in select option? I use codeigniter 3,
[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Tnx.png)

Comment: did you check that $rekening using var_dump($rekening)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: i think you are passing wrong value in order_by function.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya no error show, check my image above

Comment: Do `var_dump($data);` in controller and share output.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you have to pass value like this in modal.**

```
function all($table,$order)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from($table);
            $this->db->order_by("id_rekening",$order);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                return $query->result();
            }
        }
```

Comment: than print last execute qurery and run it in your phpmyadmin using echo $this->db->last_query(); instead of getting $query->result();

Answer (score 0):

if I get it correctly is your problem is to get all list or you want to make that option selected which is previously selected?

Here is the solution for adding value to the `<option>` in the select box. I have also added how to get the pre-selected value selected.

```
  In Model:
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from($table)
        ->order_by($order)
        ->get();

    $your_result_array = $query->result_array();
    return $your_result_array;


    In Controller:

    $data = $this->mymodel->all($data1,$data2);
    $this->load->view('client/donate/index',['data'=>$data]) ;


    Inside Your View:

    <?php

    if(isset($data) && !empty($data)){
        foreach ($data as $single_data){

        ?> <option value="<?= $data['id_rekening] ?>" <?= $your_selected_value_array['your_selected_value'] === $data['id_rekening] ? 'selected':''  ?> > <?= $data['your_other_data_column_name_here] ?> </option> <?php

        }
    }else {

          ?><option> data not found </optiop> <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i got this error sir ` Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mymodel::all2() in /home/donate/application/models/mymodel.php on line 93
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at home/donate/application/models/mymodel.php:93)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Compile Error

Message: Cannot redeclare mymodel::all()
Filename: models/mymodel.php
Line Number: 93 `

Answer (score 0):

**controller donate.php**

```
function index()
{
  $data = array('rekening' => $this->mymodel->all('rekening', 'id_rekening'));
  $this->load->view('client/donate/index', $data);
}
```

**Model donate.php**

```
function all($table,$order)
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from($table);
   $this->db->order_by($order, 'asc');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
      return FALSE;
   } else {
      return $query->result();
   }
}
```